# SQL Server Configuration Manager - Can't view Start-Mode drop-down

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-10

I have a new Windows 10 installation with SQL Server Express 2014 installed. The drop-down menu for changing the start mode doesn't show correctly:

[image: snip]

How do I circumvent / fix this? How do I change the start mode?

<sub>(I've already restarted the computer.)</sub>

Comment: Have you tried over services.msc administration console?

Comment: @Scoregraphic No. Now I did and it works fine. Thanks! You can transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: Don't use the services snapin.  That's the wrong way to manage SQL Server services.  What you need to do is run the 32-bit version of the configuration manager (i.e. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc).

Comment: @ThomasStringer That works too. Thanks! You can transform your comment into an answer. (Also, How am I supposed to know which one should be used, aside of course, from one not working as in this case?)

Comment: @ThomasStringer Perhaps this should be added to the list of programs on Windows 10 (as it is on Windows 7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into this issue a few times.  It's some sort of oddity with the 64-bit version of SQL Server Configuration Manager.

The solution here is to explicitly use the 32-bit version of SSCM by navigating to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc".  Use that version and you should be able to see the drop down options.