# SQL Server 2012 Start Mode Drop Down does not have any values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to change Start Mode for SQL Server Service, but in drop down list is empty values, does anyone has encountered such problems?
[image]

Comment: Run as administrator may be?

Comment: That `Start Mode` is the start mode of the SQL Server service. You can change it from the `Services` management console. The screenshot you posted seems to be from a *read only* form

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes, you can change it there. But this is a screenshot from Configuration Manager and it should be possible to change it here too. Note that the darker text colour for both the word "Automatic" and for the drop-down triangle indicate that *this value* should be read-write. (Other properties, I agree, are read-only)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and I found the answer on [another Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880373/13723591).

In short, what worked for me is to explicitly launch the 32-bit version of the SQL Server Configuration Manager (SSCM). If you launched SSCM by running

```
C:\Windows\System32\SQLServerManager11.msc
```

Then you need to instead run:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc
```

Note the `SysWOW64` in the path.